# Sort an array by more than one coloumn

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, 2d

I have data such as

student one 12 22 78

student two 21 24 83

student three 10 12 67

in the data file their are approx 35 students

Is their an a way to store this data in an array and then sort the data in the values in the last coloumn.

i have this and was thinking i need to use comparator function but will this allow me to sort because the array is for string but includes numbers

```
    String[][] aryStudents = new String[4][4];
    aryStudents[0][1] = "Student1";
    aryStudents[0][2] = "12";
    aryStudents[0][3] = "22";
    aryStudents[0][4] = "73";
    aryStudents[1][1] = "Student2";
    aryStudents[2][2] = "12";
    aryStudents[3][3] = "22";
    aryStudents[4][4] = "84";
```

Comment: Why not create a class `Student`? Each students having a name and a list of marks, then you can create an array of Student and sort providing a custom comparator.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by writing a custom comparator object:

```
Comparator<String[]> comp = new Comparator<>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String[] student1, String[] student2) {
        // comparison logic goes here
        // return:
        //    a negative number if student1 goes before student2
        //    0 if student1 is tied with student2
        //    a positive number if student1 goes after student2
    }
};
```

Then you can sort with:

```
Arrays.sort(aryStudents, comp);
```

As other answers have suggested, you would probably be better off defining a `Student` class to encapsulate the data for a student. You could then define the class itself to implement `Comparable<Student>` (in which case the comparison logic would be fixed) or you can define a `Comparator<Student>` object as above (except the arguments would be `(Student student1, Student student2)` instead of `(String[] student1, ...)`).

EDIT: Since you asked in a comment, here's how the comparison logic might work. If the scores are always two digits and padded with zero (so, for instance, a score of 8 would be `"08"`), then you can simply use

```
return student1[3].compareTo(student2[3]);
```

This does a lexicographic comparison, which does what you want. If a score of 8 would be represented by `"8"`, then that won't work. Instead, you will have to parse the scores as `int` values and do the comparison. As long as the integers are only two or three digits long, a nice shortcut would be:

```
return Integer.parseInt(student1[3]) - Integer.parseInt(student2[3]));
```

I've used 3 as the index of the last element because in your question code you've declared the array for each student to be length 4.

Comment: Would this not work if i have more than the two students as in my data file their are hundreds ?

Comment: @Duda777 - It would work just fine. The comparator object is passed to the `Arrays.sort()` method and is used internally to carry out the sort using a series of pair-wise comparisons. When `Arrays.sort()` returns, the entire array will be sorted according to what the comparator tells it to do.

Comment: The thing im struggling with is the comparison logic as you put it , how to i work out wether value one goes before two as i want to compare the value at the end of the array and not just by the name by just a simple if arraystudent[1][4] > arraystudent[2][4] ?? like so

Comment: @Duda777 - If the scores are always two digits and padded with zero (so, for instance, a score of 8 would be `"08"`), then you can simply use `return student1[3].compareTo(student2[3]);`. (Note that Java array indexes start at 0, so if the arrays are 4 long--as your code suggests--then the last element is at index 3.) If scores may be only a single digit, then you need to parse them as `int` values and you can then return the first minus the second (which will have the correct sign).

Answer (score 2):

Use an oriented object approach.

Create a class `Student`, each student having a name and a list of marks. Then create an array of Student and sort it providing a custom comparator. You could achieve the sort with your 2-dimensional array, but you add a level of complexity.

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private List<Integer> grades; 

    //Constructor, getter, setter, equals, hashcode, etc.
}
```

Java is an object-oriented programming language so make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

the array is for strings, but you can convert it to an int using Integer.parseInt. Then iterate over all subarrays and check the last value; put that in a comparator

```
public int compare(String[] s1, String[] s2) {
    int last = Integer.parseInt(s1[s1.length - 1]);
    int last2 = Integer.parseInt(s2[s2.length - 1]);
    return Integer.compare(last, last2);
}
```

Untested because I'm on mobile and cannot test.

Comment: With Java 7, it would be clearer (and easier) to replace the three `if` statements with `return Integer.compare(last, last2);`. That would also avoid the compiler complaining about the function possibly not executing a `return` statement. (The compiler probably isn't smart enough to figure out that one of the three `if` tests must succeed.) Alternatively, replace the last `if` with an unconditional `return -1;`.

Comment: I dont undrestand how i could adapt this to work if i had more than two students

Comment: @Duda777 Use the Array.sort method with this comparator

Answer (score -1):

Be careful arrays first index starts with 0 th element.Your solution will be throw a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.